# Thumbnail image wont change main image in gallery in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I trying to create a gallery with thumbnail images and once click the main image changes to that thumbnail. I currently have the thumbnails and the main image displaying but when I click on a thumbnail the main image doesn't change.

I'm using the following JQuery that changes the end of the source file.
In my images folder I have both thumbnail images (with the suffix _thumb) and large images (with the suffix _large). Not sure where i'm going wrong, if you need anymore information please ask.

HTML head script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
            <div id="panel">
                <img id="largeImage" src="images/foldingbike_large.jpg" />
                <div id="description">First image description</div>
            </div>

            <div id="thumbs">
                <img src="images/foldingbike_thumb.jpg" alt="1st image description" />
                <img src="images/foldingbike2_thumb.jpg" alt="2nd image description" />

             </div>
```

CSS

```
#thumbs { padding-top: 10px; overflow: hidden; }
#thumbs img, #largeImage {
 border: 1px solid gray;
 padding: 4px;
 background-color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#thumbs img {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 6px;
}
#description {
 background: black;
 color: white;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 width: 525px;
 margin: 5px;
}
#panel { position: relative; }

$('#thumbs img').click(function(){
    $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
    $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
});
```

Comment: Check out your CSS file. Are you putting jquery code inside css file?

Comment: Yea the jquery is inside the CSS, trying all sorts of things but it doesn't want to work.

Comment: This will not work. Put jquery inside <script> tag in your html or in a separete js file. Never inside CSS.

Comment: Thanks that works, unsure what I was thinking there!